# Chromebook : can't attach file to e-mail

Tags: java, android, android-fileprovider, chromebook

I have a (big) problem on chromebook with a functionnality working fine on "classic" android devices (phones, tablets).

I try to send an e-mail with an attached file.

Here's a portion of code (api>=23).

> ```
>         Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
>         String[] str = new String[1];
>         str[0] = "destination@yahoo.fr";
>         email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, str);
>
>         email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My text");
>         email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My subject");
>
>         Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.TTT.fileprovider", new File(dest));
>
>         email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
>
>         email.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
>                 | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
>                 | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
>
>         email.setType("message/rfc822");
>
>         startActivity(email);
> ```

On my Phone (android 9 api 28), gmail app is called, all text fields are filled with correct information and the file (myResume.pdf) is correctly attached.

When sent then received, the e-mail contains a readable pdf file. that's cool.

With my chromebook (PB 314 / v. 83.0.4103.119), gmail is called, all text fields are filled with correct information **but no attached file**.

LogCat indicates :

```
2020-06-27 15:25:50.886 127-2348/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=message/rfc822 flg=0x43 cmp=org.chromium.arc.applauncher/.ChromeBrowserProxyActivity clip={message/rfc822 T:My text} (has extras)} from uid 10040
2020-06-27 15:25:50.887 565-565/? D/ArcDummy: New intent received: Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=message/rfc822 flg=0x10000043 cmp=org.chromium.arc.applauncher/.ChromeBrowserProxyActivity clip={message/rfc822 T:My text} (has extras) }
2020-06-27 15:25:50.887 565-565/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startService:1531 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:664 org.chromium.arc.applauncher.DummyActivity.forwardIntentIfNeeded:155 org.chromium.arc.applauncher.DummyActivity.onNewIntent:121 android.app.Activity.performNewIntent:7255 
2020-06-27 15:25:50.892 127-2348/? W/WindowManagerInjector: Attempted to get menu state of app token with non existing window
2020-06-27 15:25:50.896 780-842/? D/ArcMediaControllerManager: onTaskMovedToFront: 2
2020-06-27 15:25:50.897 780-842/? I/ArcMediaControllerManager: onAppBecameActive: org.chromium.arc.applauncher
2020-06-27 15:25:50.892 127-2348/? W/WindowManagerInjector: Attempted to get menu state of app token with non existing window
2020-06-27 15:25:50.900 127-760/? W/ActivityManager: For security reasons, the system cannot issue a Uri permission grant to content://com.TTT.fileprovider/images/myResume.pdf [user 0]; use startActivityAsCaller() instead
2020-06-27 15:25:50.901 127-760/? W/WindowManagerInjector: Attempted to get menu state of app token with non existing window
```

when testing on android phones, this sentence never appears :

```
For security reasons, the system cannot issue a Uri permission grant to content://com.TTT.fileprovider/images/myResume.pdf [user 0]; use startActivityAsCaller() instead
```

more information about previous code :

```
the file "myResume.pdf" is copied to a special directory for beeing shared with gmail.
    
dest is a string (/storage/emulated/0/MyDir/myResume.pdf) obtained with
    
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() > /storage/emulated/0/
my sub directory, created and verified > MyDir/
the file > myResume.pdf
```

the file AndroidManifest.xml includes

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.TTT.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

the file @xml/provider_paths is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="images"  path="myDir/"/>
    </paths>
```

I hope I have explained my problem with all details,
Can anyone help me?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Rather than putting the file in external storage, try putting it in internal storage (e.g., `getCacheDir()`), and see if you have better luck. Note that you will need to update your `provider_paths` to match.

Comment: thanks @CommonsWare.
I tried. same problem. works with phone. doesn't work with chromebook. fn=/data/user/0/com.TTT/cache/myDir/myResume.pdf
... For security reasons, the system cannot issue a Uri permission grant to content:
 //com.TTT.fileprovider/imagesBis/myResume.pdf [user 0]; use startActivityAsCaller() instead 
(<cache-path name="imagesBis"  path="myDir/"/>)

Answer (score 2):

the problem is finally solved by using gmail app (after downloaded it) then using it instead of gmail/web/chrome.